# Is there a way to import environment variables in Google App Engine's app.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine

I know you can declare `env_variables` in your `app.yaml` as described in the [app.yaml documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref). However, is it possible to include environment variables from your local environment into `app.yaml` when deploying.

As an example of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
# in app.yaml
runtime: python27
api_version:1
threadsafe: true
service: {{ $AN_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no such templating support exists for the `app.yaml` configuration files.

Side note: the `app.yaml` file is not only used to extract deployment instructions information, it's also used to configure the operation of the respective service on GAE. Making the service name configurable in such manner doesn't make a lot of sense unless the services being deployed are identical in every aspect (other than their name) - highly unlikely.

One possible approach for environment-specific deployment would be to have different version control branches for the app code, one for each environment, each having the desired `app.yaml` content.

Another one would be to wrap the deployment command in a script and perform the enviroment substitutions inside that script.

As for passing credentials info to the app a clean, straight-forward solution is not yet available. But approaches exist:

- [GAE: best practices for storing secret keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501234/gae-best-practices-for-storing-secret-keys)
- [How to set environment variables/app secrets in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875751/how-to-set-environment-variables-app-secrets-in-google-app-engine)
- [Google app engine: Best practice for hiding Rails secret keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968349/google-app-engine-best-practice-for-hiding-rails-secret-keys)
- [How to handle sensitive configuration information when deploying app-engine applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336414/how-to-handle-sensitive-configuration-information-when-deploying-app-engine-appl/31347185#31347185)

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't actually intend to use it on `service` specifically. I just wanted a short example that conveys the desired behavior. My actual intention was to use it to include secrets as environment variables, but I thought environment variables inside environment variables would confuse the question. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @voscausa That seems more targeted for being used by apps, but I don't see mentioning about being used for managing the apps themselves. I may have missed it, tho', I just glanced through it. Worth a closer look probably.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use `includes:` to specify an array of files to be included. And in the included file, you can specify `env_variables:` just like you do in `app.yaml`.
Example: `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

env_variables:
  FIST_VAR: myFirstVar

includes:
- credentials.yaml
```

`credentials.yaml`:

```
env_variables:
  SECOND_VAR: mySecondVar
```